# What is this sizeof trick doing?

Tags: c, sizeof

It's been a while since I looked at C code, but I'm trying to make sure I understand what's going on here. Someone has declared this (has more members in their code):

```
int trysizes[] = { 64, 64, 128, 64, };
```

Then later they use this as part of a for loop:

```
sizeof(trysizes)/sizeof*(trysizes)
```

I'm thinking the first part is the number of bytes in the array and the second part must be the size of each array member giving us the number of items in the array. Is this a standard way to calculate array length and what is the second sizeof actually doing?

Comment: Whenever I need this "trick" I usually do a `#define` for it, since it often comes handy.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, after fixing the confusing syntax so this becomes

```
sizeof(trysizes)/sizeof(*trysizes)
```

or even better

```
sizeof(trysizes)/sizeof(trysizes[0])
```

this is the preferred way of computing the number of elements of an array. The second `sizeof` indeed computes the size of element `0` of the array.

Note that this only works when `trysizes` is actually an array, not a pointer to one.

Comment: Yes, I find the 'sizeof (arr[0])' is much easier to brain-parse.

Comment: Ok yeah, sizeof(arr[0]) is easier for me too, particularly not having written this stuff in a while! Thanks.

Comment: `sizeof *array` is more elegant, I'd say. And the superfluous braces make it look worse. Should be `sizeof array / sizeof *array`.

Comment: @AndreyT: that's a matter of opinion. To me, `[0]` is much more suggestive of an array than `*`.

Comment: Btw, omitting the parentheses might be not a typo. The code compiles and works as expected. I have first encountered sizeof without parentheses in "Expert C Programming" by Peter van der Linden. However, this notation isn't allowed with types i.e. we can't write sizeof TYPE. Anyway, the expression without parentheses looks very confusing.

Comment: @Negai: you're right. It is *very* confusing the way the OP cites it, though.

Comment: @larsmans: I just don't like that fact that element `[0]` is singled out as if it is somehow special :) If you want to involve a specific index, at least make it `42`: `sizeof *array / sizeof array[42]`

Comment: `[0]` pointlessly takes more typing and is overspecific; `*` is indicative that is is the element type. But who cares if you bury it in a macro, as you should: `#define ARRAYLEN(a) (sizeof(a)/sizeof *(a))` [which, BTW, shows that the original syntax was correct -- in a macro, the parens need to surround the argument]

Comment: @AndreyT: since `*a` means the same as `a[0]`, it singles out the same element. And I find `42` confusing, since I reserve that for random seeds in unit tests ;)

Answer (score 1):

You got it. The second `sizeof` in the denominator de-references the first element of the array, yielding the size of element `0`. `sizeof` knows the total buffer size of an array variable - the numerator - and so this idiom will yield the number of elements in the array.

In my experience this is an uncommon expression of this particular idiom, usually I've seen, and *I use*:

```
sizeof(var)/sizeof(var[0]);
```

This more clearly identifies the variable as an array and not a pointer.

This is a pretty common trick, but be aware that it only works if the variable is declared as an array, e.g. this won't work on an array that's been converted to a pointer as a function parameter.

Comment: "this is an uncommon expression of this particular idiom" -- nonsense. As a C programmer for 3 1/2 decades, I've seen the `*` version far more often ... usually hidden away in a macro in a header file, as experienced and competent programmers do rather than repeating this expression with greater risk of a typo and misallocation.

Comment: @JimBalter I defer, my decades are fewer. But in them I've almost always seen array subscripts used.

Answer (score 1):

The keypiont is that,when using sizeof, although we mostly use `int a; sizeof(a);` , we can also omit the parentheses, like this: `int a; sizeof a;`
So in this case, `sizeof*(trysizes) == sizeof *trysizes == sizeof(*trysizes)`